# Internet Explorer submits the wrong button

Tags: internet-explorer, xhtml

I have an HTML form with two buttons as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Yes, Delete"  />
<button name="confirm" type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="No, Go Back">No, Go Back</button>
```

Now, when I click on either in Firefox, the behavior is as expected.  If I click the submit button, then "Yes, Delete" gets posted and if I click "No, Go Back" it's as if I hit the back button on the browser.  However, in Internet Explorer (6 or 8), if I click on "Yes, Delete" then "No, Go Back" gets posted.  Why is that?

Comment: Is it because both of the names are the same perhaps?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? Change one name, retest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera ***all play*** the "***first match wins***" game, but IE plays the "*last match wins*" game.

([see bug/feature report here](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/06/bug-or-feature-round-three.html))

In general, I would name the buttons differently unless they are part of a radio/checkbox set.

Answer (score 2):

Because the control with the name “confirm” has the value “No, Go Back”.

Comment: “Because there is a control with the name ‘confirm’ that has the value ‘No, Go Back’”? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, There are issues with having more than one `<button>` element in Internet Explorer (even IE7). Check out [here](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/forms/multiple-submit-buttons.html) and [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE) for example.

I found this out when trying to make a "Save / Update / Delete" kind of page with three `<BUTTON>` elements - worked perfectly in Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the names of both buttons are the same.  The second button must be "overriding" the attributes of the first button.  At any rate, changing the name of the second button solved the problem.